# How to enable wifi in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using a Macbook with Parallels 11.2.0

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, macbook, parallels

I have Ubuntu as a Virtual Machine in Parallel I am using a Macbook.

I've tried to search for the drivers in the Software & Updates but it does not find the WiFi drivers. I also tried several commands in the terminal like:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Those commands downloaded and extracted some drivers but it didn't enable WiFi.

Nothing seems to work. I don't know if this is a problem in Ubuntu or a combination of Parallels and Ubuntu. I only see the Wired connection but not the Wireless.

This is the info of my Wireless Card:

- Card Type:    AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0xF5)
- Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

The only connection I have available is Wired.

[image]

Comment: On my computer, virtual machines in VirtualBox don't see my wifi connection directly. They just use a *virtual* wired connection created by VirtualBox, which pipes everything through the host's network connection (i.e. my wifi connection). I can browse the web, etc as normal through this virtual wired connection. Maybe Parallels works the same way?

Comment: It appears to be a common problem between the different virtual machine systems and Ubuntu. I've been doing research and what I find is that the only way to connect to the Internet in a VM is using the Host's connection (through a Bridge Wired Connection). This limits the capabilities of Ubuntu... Thanks for your answer Nick.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your question postet more than a year ago:

I run a Macbook Pro with the same card and am changing to linux via efi dual boot. First I installed ubuntu but had to fix a startupbug ("minimum bash line...). 
Linuxmint 18.2 recognized my Airport out of the box and connected to internet. But I am trying to learn debian 9. Debian did not recognize my card.
I am not familiar with terminal yet but I found a solution. After hours of studying forums, searching for the proper driver, installing the wrong ones...

I checked in my Mint version with synaptic for drivers it used and there it was:  bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64

I made a google search and found a deb file here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1

The file name is: bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64.deb

I installed it in Debian and it worked promptly. But running synaptic to uninstall the other Broadcom Sta files, I lost it again. Now I reinstalled it new and it works fine.

Hope I can help someone with this post to save time and frustration.

good luck